# Can I generate Validation From MVC Model (.net Core ) To Client Angular and android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Can I Use Model Validation In .net Core Web API Such as

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public String Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} 
     characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

}
```

To Generate Form Or Validation Model in Client Angular
, Android and IOS
I Want To Write Model once and Generate all 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something exists, but is not designed for the current state-of-the-art, afaik.

Microsoft have put good effort to provide client side unobstrusive libraries, but it was designed for the ASP.NET MVC Framework. The annotations in the classes are translated into html attributes that are interpreted by a jQuery plugin: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/

This also implies that you will generate your html server-side (Razor or similar). Otherwise you'll have to put the html attributes by hand. In that case, I don't see enough benefit than do server-side attributes + AngularJs-style validation.